# Boxfuse Internal Error : null

Tags: cloudcaptain

[image]I am using boxfuse to upload my spring boot app to AWS. Everything was working fine yesterday . Today , none of commands of boxfuse are working . It is showing : `Internal Error : null` . Please help me to solve this . Thanks .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely due to a bug in this older version of the client that is being triggered by our latest Console update.

Simply upgrade your client with `boxfuse -u` and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Hi Axel , running the above command also return the same error .

Comment: Please try again. Should be fixed now.